# Stop Passwords Storing For Windows Application Logon

Tags: windows, windows-10, credentials-manager

Currently using Microsoft Dynamics and they're using this Windows login box.

How can i disable this remember me option, either hide this tick box or stop credential manager working for this one application? I dont want to fully disable credential manager.

I have enabled the local security policy **Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication** and RSOP confirmed it was enabled but it still saves the password and prefills if a user clicks **Remember Me**

Workstation is Win 10 Pro non domain.

[image]

Comment: Setting the registry value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableDomainCreds to 1. This will disable storage of credentials for the whole system.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no supported way to disable credential storage for just one application/credential. No Registry checks made by the CredUI dialog seem at all promising; denying access to the credential store on the file system doesn't work because LSASS remembers the credential in memory. Possible hacky approaches: [1] set up a scheduled task to delete the saved credential, [2] create a [custom compatibility shim](https://github.com/Fleex255/CustomShim/) to alter the `CredUIPromptForCredentialsA` call. Writing an answer for 2 would be hard because Dynamics is not freely available.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar before but this would not be a answer for all applications. Since Dynamics would connect to the same host this should work.

Create a batch file with this and change the **your-server-string** to your servers address. This will delete anything with that name on startup.

```
echo Deleting Saved Credentials...
cmdkey /delete:your-server-string
echo Starting Microsoft Dynamics...
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central\140\RoleTailored Client\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.exe"
```

To make it more assteticlly pleasing on the user you can create a shortcut to the batch file and change the icon of the shortcut to the one of Microsoft Dynamics.